# IIS 6 closes connection - how to keep it persistent?

Tags: iis-6, http-headers, windows-authentication

My company has two test servers modelled after customer configurations,

- one with Windows Server 2003 SP2, IIS 6 and Tomcat 5.5,
- one with Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7 and Tomcat 6.

Both IIS are configured to use Windows Authentication and have an ISAPI filter for Tomcat.

With the IIS 6 machine, the server closes every authenticated http connection by sending the header "Connection: close". With the IIS 7 machine, the server uses persistent connections, and sends the header "Persistent-Auth: true". The customer with IIS 6 has the same connection-closing behaviour as our test server, which triples the number of network roundtrips due to NTLM authentication.

Why is the IIS 6 server closing connections, and how can I make it use persistent connections?

I have RDP admin access to both servers, and will happily provide any useful information and make experiments.

**UPDATE:**

I found that the problem is partially caused by an outdated version of the ISAPI filter (isapi_redirect.dll). After updating that filter to 1.2.32, I no longer get the "Connection: close" header for html pages. However, I still get it when the client applet accesses a service which returns serialized Java objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem had nothing to do with authentication. The Tomcat servlet uses **[chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)** for its response, and the ISAPI filter was not configured to handled it, which seems to force IIS 6 to close the connection. IIS 7 seems to collect the response chunks, and sends the whole response, un-chunked, to the caller.

After upgrading to version 1.2.32 and enabling chunked encoding using the `enable_chunked_encoding` property of the ISAPI filter, as described in the [reference guide](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html), connections are no longer closed.